# in excel, a formula with no references to other cells changes all cells value when editing one of the cells

Tags: excel-formula

if i use a formula like this, which doesn't have any reference to any other cell:
`=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,42949),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,42949),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,42949),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,42949),4))`
and paste it to multiple cells on a sheet, then simple double click a cell and hit enter (no changes), all the cells that have that formula change value.
Anybody know why?

Comment: `RANDBETWEEN` is volatile and as such any change to Excel while this sheet is open will cause it to recalculate.

Comment: BTW: if you have TEXTJOIN it can be simplfied: `=TEXTJOIN("-",,DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,16^{8;4;4;4;8}-1),{8;4;4;4;8}))&DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,16^4-1),4)` depending on version may need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Excel has the concept of 'volatile functions'. These include RAND , NOW, TODAY.  Volatiles are recalculated when the book is opened and whenever a cell is edited.

Comment: But in this case, it's not just the cell being edited that's changing value it's all cells that use this same formula?
Does the volatility mean that any use of Randbetween will cause other cells to recacl, cause that's what's happening?

Comment: It happens if ANY cell is edited

Comment: thanks much (seems strange that it would do that)

Comment: so if that's the case, any tips on how to use that formula without it being volatile?

Comment: @ksully add the forma into the equls bar and hit f9. Copy the raw value

Comment: @ksully or copy paste the values over the top, thus removing the formulas.